# Using an enum from a type library in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, enums, automation, idl

I'm implementing a COM interface for an existing application written in C++. The COM interface is used for automating the application from VBScript.

One of the methods I want to call via th COM interface has a parameter that, in C++, has an `enum` type. I have defined a corresponding `enum` type in the IDL file, and `oleview` shows the values are registered:

```
// Copied from type library viewer    
typedef enum
{
   MyValueA = 0,
   MyValueB = 1,
   MyValueC = 2
} MyEnum;
```

However, when I pass one of these values in VBScript, the value received by the CPP implementation is always 0. I assume I'm not using the correct VBScript syntax. Passing an integer value directly works, and passing something random (like `ghfitgr`) also results in 0, which is probably what is happening to `MyValueB`, etc.

I found a claim that `enum.member` should be used, which would be `MyEnum.MyValue`, but that results in a syntax error (`object required: MyEnum`). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend you to read http://goo.gl/88n6F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late-bindng VBScript can't/won't pluck those info from the .dll, all you get are objects (by CreateObject()) and what they provide. So spare yourself a lot of hassle & hacks by defining the values with decent names using **Const**.

**To clarify:**

I meant: **Const** in the VBScript code.

Comment: I added `const int HorClassic = 1;`, but nothing changed. In fact, the type library viewer doesn't even display the identifier. I made another change to the type library, which does show up, so it's not a registration issue. Actually I don't undertand why late binding would fail to use `enum` values but succeed in using `const` values.